# Clicking between two links to check their existence using 'if-else-if'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm sorry about the title I do not know ho to state it more simpler.

I'm really confused right now. so I'm using the `driver.find_element_by_link_text()` command. Below is my  case

```
OASIS = "OASIS-C1 Nurse Start of Care"
OASISRecert = "OASIS-C1 Nurse Recert"

oasis = driver.find_element_by_link_text(OASIS)
oasisrecert = driver.find_element_by_link_text(OASISRecert)
```

at times there are some pages that contain only *OASIS*
and other times *OASISRecert* and these two can't be on the same page so it's one or the other

**How do i turn this into an if-else-if statement?**

what I mean is if the page contains the *OASIS-C1 Nurse Start of Care* do this

elif the page contains *OASIS-C1 Nurse Recert* do that.

**How can this be done?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Other element locater instead of using *Linktext*,
beacuse the linktest *OASIS* and *OASISRecert* may conflict though i understand they can not be present of the same page.

Below is my approach to handle the situation.

First store both the Webelements, say *OASIS* and *OASISRecert*.
As you stated these two can't be on the same page so it's one or the other.
Use

```
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("OASISRecert"))
{
Do action 1 
{
else 
{
Do action 2
}
```

Comment: is that in java? i tried it and it spits out an error. Im using python

whats the python equivalent of this command .getPageSource()?

I think we're almost there

Comment: Can  you help with the error message? and also update the new code you tried.

Comment: I got it. with the help of your answer. it was really simple

"if OASIS in driver.page_source:" 

that did the trick. thank you very much for your help

Comment: Glad it worked. Cheers. Will appreciate if you mark my code as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't understand what is the problem?

First you check for OASISRecert, then in elif you check OASIS. Something like:

```
if driver.find_element_by_link_text(OASISRecert):
   doSomething()
elif driver.find_element_by_link_text(OASIS):
   doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: it's ok thank you for the answer I found the solution.

"if OASIS in driver.page_source:
   doSomething()"

that did the trick. thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is the python equivalent code

```
if "xxx" in driver.page_source():
        condition1
else:
        condition2
```